# Is Storing Data Objects Multiple Times for Different Query Keys in React Query a Standard Practice?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm new to React Query and I've noticed that each time I perform a query, it stores the data object within that specific query.

For instance, when I use:

```
  useQuery({
    queryKey: ['posts'],
    queryFn: ...
  });
```

And also have:

```
  useQuery({
    queryKey: ['posts', 1],
    queryFn: ...
  });
```

It seems to store the object `{ id: 1 }` twice, correct? Once for the posts key and again for the posts-1 key.

I'm wondering if this is the correct approach. If I have a page displaying all posts and also retrieve each post individually, it seems to duplicate the data, potentially leading to high memory usage.

Is this the standard method of handling data in React Query?

Answer (score 1):

## Is Storing Data Objects Multiple Times for Different Query Keys in React Query a Standard Practice?

Storing data objects multiple times for different query keys is a common practice, though whether it's "standard" is very debatable. It depends on the specifics of your app.

## Benefits of this approach

It can be a very practical approach because it can give you:

- Component-Level isolation
- Flexibility in data fetching
- Simplified state management
- More control over caching and updates
- Consistency in data structures
- Performance Optimizations: For example, you can use the `initialData` option to initialize a query with data from another query, reducing the need for redundant network requests.

## Should you keep it this way?

If your application deals with a large amount of data or very complex objects, duplicated data might lead to increased memory usage as you said. Think about whether React Query works for your case long term or whether you will need to consider a different workflow (e.g. normalizing data and using React Query mostly for fetching data). Utilizing React Query's power to the full will mitigate any potential setbacks with memory usage. As with any app, it is important to think big and map things through before starting to work on it to avoid a lot of refactoring later on.

## My two cents

In most cases, the benefits of React Query outweigh any drawbacks it may have. We very recently switched from Redux Saga to React Query and I wouldn't go back to the old approach for anything.